# Solve differential equation $y-2x+1-(2y+1-x)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y-2x+1-(2y+1-x)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
I tried to simplify it to linear differential equation but it did not work.
Trying separable differential equation and I got:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2x+1+y}{2y+1-x}$$
This is not separable, I think. I'm not sure which way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the differential equation as

$$(y-2x+1)dx + (x-2y-1)dy = 0 $$

Notice that

$$\frac{\partial (x-2y-1)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial (y-2x+1)}{\partial y} = 1$$

so this is an exact differential equation (i.e. the original differential equation was of the form $f_x dx+ f_ydy = 0$ for some $f(x,y)$). Solving for $f$, we get that

$$f(x,y) = xy - x^2 + x -y^2 - y + C$$

Therefore the solution to this differential equation is

$$xy + x - y - x^2 - y^2 = C$$

where $C$ is determined by the initial conditions. $y$ can be solved for via quadratic equation if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is exact as was solved by Ninad Munshi a minute ago.

I am offering a new solution by a linear change of variable namely $x=X+a$ and $y=Y+b$ and finding $a$ and $b$ to change your equation in to a homogeneous by making the constants equal zero.

For this question we have $a=1/5$ and $b=-3/5$ which turns the equation into $$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{-2X+Y}{2Y-X}$$

This method works in similar cases even if the equation is not exact.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:
$$(y-2x+1)dx + (x-2y-1)dy = 0$$
$$ ydx+xdy+(-2x+1)dx-(2y+1)dy=0$$
Note that $xdy+ydx=d(xy)$
$$d(xy)+(-2x+1)dx-(2y+1)dy=0$$
Integrate :
$$xy-x^2+x-y^2-y=K$$